# Google Chrome freezes up when closing tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Has anyone come across this problem?
Chrome freezes up when closing two or three opened tabs, there is no other option but to close the down the browser and restart, this happened since last update: Version 45.0.2454.101.

Comment: Do you have Crashplan?

Comment: Just to let other users who experience above issues; I resolved the problem by installing the Google Chrome beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let other users who experience above issues; 
I resolved the problem by installing the Google Chrome beta version.